# Glassfish v3: Can't Deploy MessageDriven Bean - Missing Destination JNDI Name

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, glassfish-3, message-driven-bean

I am trying to deploy an ear that contains an EJB jar.  The jar only contains one MDB class:

```
package my.package;

import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.ObjectMessage;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@MessageDriven(mappedName = "jms/FileUploadedQueue", activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue") })
public class FileListener implements MessageListener
{
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileListener.class);

    public FileListener()
    {
        // empty constructor
    }

    public void onMessage(Message message)
    {
        try
        {
            log.info("Received message: " + ((TextMessage)message).getText());
        }
        catch (JMSException ex)
        {
            String error = "Received error code '"
                    + ex.getErrorCode()
                    + "' retrieving message from queue jms/FileUploadedQueue.";

            Exception linkedEx = ex.getLinkedException();

            if (linkedEx != null)
            {
                log.error(error += "Linked exception: ", linkedEx);
            }
            else
            {
                log.error(error, linkedEx);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using Glassfish 3.1.1 (build 12) admin console, I have setup the following:

**Resources -> JMS Resources -> Connection Factories:**

```
Pool Name = jms/ConnectionFactory
JNDI Name = jms/ConnectionFactory
Resource Type = javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
```

**Resources -> JMS Resources -> JMS Destination Resources:**

```
JNDI Name = jms/FileUploadedQueue
Resource Type = javax.jms.Queue
```

**Configurations -> server-config -> Java Message Service:**

```
Type = EMBEDDED
```

When I try to deploy the ear containing the EJB jar, I get this error:

```
WARNING: PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called
INFO: GUI deployment: uploadToTempfile
INFO: uploadFileName=FileProcessor-ear-1.0.ear

SEVERE: Class [ Lorg/slf4j/Logger; ] not found. Error while loading [ class my.package.FileListener ]
SEVERE: Missing Destination JNDI Name
SEVERE: MDB00017: [FileListener]: Exception in creating message-driven bean container: [com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Error in Runtime DD: missing destination JNDI name]
SEVERE: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException
com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Error in Runtime DD: missing destination JNDI name
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jms.system.ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.updateMDBRuntimeInfo(ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.java:1855)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:186)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.<init>(MessageBeanContainer.java:205)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:186)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:257)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:202)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:184)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

SEVERE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer load method
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:186)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:257)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:202)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:184)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Error in Runtime DD: missing destination JNDI name
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jms.system.ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.updateMDBRuntimeInfo(ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.java:1855)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:186)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.<init>(MessageBeanContainer.java:205)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:230)
    ... 55 more

SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error
com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Error in Runtime DD: missing destination JNDI name
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jms.system.ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.updateMDBRuntimeInfo(ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.java:1855)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:186)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.<init>(MessageBeanContainer.java:205)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:186)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:257)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:202)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:184)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)    

INFO: Exception Occurred :Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error. Please see server.log for more details.
```

Have I missed some Glassfish configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I replaced the slf4j logging with simple System.out statement to eliminate that as an issue.  I got a different error with this root cause:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MQJMSRA_AS4001: setDestination:Invalid destination name=jms/FileUploadedQueue
```

This issue was because I set the "Physical Destination Name" to "jms/FileUploadedQueue" (same as JNDI name). However, the destination name has greater restrictions on valid characters. Changing it to simply "FileUploadedQueue" allowed it to be deployed. From http://markmail.org/message/zetfwrp2hlesynje:

> Yes - the failure is due to the "queue/myDestination" being 'Illegal' syntax for
>   the particular JMS provider's physical destination naming syntax - which is
>   provider dependent and not standardized. In this case, GF includes Sun Java
>   System Message Queue and the rules for legal destination names are set by JMQ.
>   Unfortunately, this is not easy to find in the docs - but if you look hard
>   enough, you'll find the following in the MQ Admin Guide on physical destination
>   names.
>
> The physical destination name. The naming rules are as follows:
>
> The name must contain only alphanumeric characters. It cannot contain
>   spaces. * The name can begin with an alphabetic character, the underscore character
>   (_ ) or the dollar sign ($)."

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. The problem was:

@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "jms/SampleTopic")

This need to be

@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "SampleTopic")